# Spring Kafka got an infinite retry attempt

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Spring Kafka got an infinite retry attempt

Version: Spring-Kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE

Listener setting

```
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setRetryTemplate(getRetryTemplate());
    factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);

    return factory;
  }
```

And using a RetryTemplate with SimpleRetryPolicy for setting the MaxAttempts

Kafka Listener

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "topic")
  public void myListener(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
      //Code here
  }
```

Some strange issue is happening on server with multiple instance running. So whenever `myListener` throwing an exception, the message will be retried up to the max attempt and ACK'ed fine on local.

But on the server, the following is happen:

```
Node A: Consume #1 -> Retry #1 -> Retry #1 -> Consume #2 -> Retry #2 -> Retry #2 -> Consume #3 ....

Node B:...................................... Consume #1 -> Retry #1 -> Retry #1 -> Consume #2 ....
```

And so on without any ACK. After 500 Message (ex: Consume #500), node A reset again back to Consume #1. Not sure if the number #500 is having any relation to [max.poll.records](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.poll.records)

Still can't reproducing the issue on local setup since it's working fine (ACK after maxAttempt).

But is there any kind of explanation/solution for this problem? currently the shortcut is just catch the exception and prevent the retrying mechanism so the message can be ACK and offset moving forwards.

Thanks!

---

Update:

```
Node A: Consume #1 -> Retry #1 -> Retry #1 -> Consume #2 -> Retry #2 -> Retry #2 -> Consume #3 ....

Node B:...................................... Consume #1 -> Retry #1 -> Retry #1 -> Consume #2 ....
```

- After further reading, found out that this is indeed how kafka will proceed if the message is not ACK'ed. So the service will continue to proceed the message without any ACK but if there's a trigger like restart (or in this case the max poll records), service need to continue read again it will start from the latest ACK'ed message which is Message#1. The same group that read from the topic (Node A and B) will also start from latest offset.
- So the root cause of the problem is Spring Kafka somehow not ACK'ing any message that it consume after retrying X-Times.
- The workaround is to implement manual ACK, so every consumed message add some counter and increase that counter, if it's already surpassed X-times, manually ACK the message without sending any retry attempt.

Comment: 2.2.x is no longer supported; https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support - the `RetryTemplate` was deprecated long ago and is removed in current versions; its functionality is replaced by an appropriately configured `DefaultErrorHandler`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling